# How to set width for sap.m.Popover?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a popover upon a button click. The [popover](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/explored/index.html#page|%7B%22id%22%3A%22controls%22%7D|0) over is working fine however when I try to set the width for the popover it is not working, here is what I did:

```
 sap.m.Popover.setContentWidth("someWidth");
```

I am using SAPUI5 version 1.12. Is there any particular considerations I am missing?

EDIT: It seems like this is a bug in version 1.12, because the width content setter works as expected in later versions!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working with SAPUI5 1.12, this behavior works as expected in later versions. As a work around to this problem in SAP UI5 1.12 you can define a scroll container for which you can set the width and put in it all the content of the popover, then define this scroll container as the content for the popover. For instance, here is the scroll container

```
var TheScrollContainer = new sap.m.ScrollContainer({
            width : "250px",
            horizontal : false,
            vertical : true,
            content : [UIComponents]
        });
```

and here is the popover:

```
 var thePopover = new sap.m.Popover("configuration_popover", {
            title: "some title", 
            placement: sap.m.PlacementType.Top, 
            footer: new sap.m.Bar({
                contentRight: [new sap.m.Button({
                    text: 'close', 
                    press: function(){
                        thePopover .close();
                    }
                })]
            }), 
            content: TheScrollContainer 
        });
```

this way the popover will take the width of the scroll container and the problem is resolved!

Mohamed Ali